# Unable to resolve 2 equivalent geodesic equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, geodesics

A free particle moves along geodesics, one form being

\begin{split}
\ddot x^\mu &= -\Gamma^{\mu}_{\sigma \rho} \dot x^\sigma \dot x^\rho \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu}(\partial_\sigma g_{\rho \nu} + \partial_\rho g_{\sigma \nu} - \partial_\nu g_{\rho \sigma}) \dot x^\sigma \dot x^\rho
\end{split}

Applying the lowering operator, we have

\begin{split}
\ddot x_\mu &= g_{\mu \alpha} \ddot x^\alpha \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\delta^\mu_\nu(\partial_\sigma g_{\rho \nu} + \partial_\rho g_{\sigma \nu} - \partial_\nu g_{\rho \sigma}) \dot x^\sigma \dot x^\rho
\end{split}
Hence
$$\tag{1}
\ddot x_{\mu} = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\sigma g_{\rho \mu} + \partial_\rho g_{\sigma \mu} - \partial_\mu g_{\rho \sigma}) \dot x^\sigma \dot x^\rho
$$

Equivalently, using the intrinsic derivative,

$$
\frac{Dt_\mu}{D\tau} = 0 $$ for a free particle, so $$
 \frac{dt_\mu}{d\tau} = \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu \rho} \dot x_\sigma \dot x^\rho 
$$

or

$$
\ddot x_\mu = \frac{1}{2}g^{\sigma \nu}(\partial_\mu g_{\rho \nu} + \partial_\rho g_{\mu \nu} - \partial_\nu g_{\rho \mu}) \dot x_\sigma \dot x^\rho  
$$
Hence
$$\tag{2}
\ddot x_\mu= \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu g_{\sigma \rho}\dot x^\sigma \dot x^\rho  
$$
(The summation on $\sigma$ and $\rho$ in the last two terms cancels)

Clearly (1) $\neq$ (2). Does anyone know where my reasoning has gone astray?

Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariant derivative of $g$ is zero, but it's ordinary derivative isn't. You need to know what is $\ddot{x_\mu}$,

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_{\mu} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(g_{\mu\nu} x^{\nu} ) = g_{\mu\nu} \ddot{x}^{\nu} + \ddot{g}_{\mu\nu} x^{\nu} + 2\dot{g}_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^{\nu}  \ne g_{\mu\nu} \ddot{x}^{\nu}
\end{equation}
That's the mistake you made in equation (1).

To get agreement, you need to know what is the meaning of vector $t_{\mu}$ in your equation. I think that's actually the components of the dual of the velocity vector, 
\begin{equation}
t_{\mu} = g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^{\nu} 
\end{equation}
notice that $g_{\mu\nu}$ is not inside the time derivative, that's how we lower indices by [musical isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

Plug in this definition of $t_{\mu}$ and you will get the standard geodesic equation. In fact, equation (2) is the Euler-Lagrangian equation for the action,
\begin{equation}
S = \int d\tau \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^{\mu} \dot{x}^{\nu} 
\end{equation}
whose solution gives the distance minimizing curve(with affine parameterization): the geodesic.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is important to distinguish between the ordinary and covariant derivative of the metric.